# Date field literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle, select, date-formatting

I have a field called program_start_date that is formatted as `YYYYMM`. I need to determine if this date occurs 5 years ago or less, if it occurs more than 5 years ago, or if it is blank.

I have the following case statement in my SQL query:

```
CASE
   WHEN floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, program_start_date)/12) <= 5 THEN '5 years or less'
   WHEN floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, program_start_date)/12) > 5 THEN '6+ years'
   WHEN program_start_date is null THEN 'Blank'
   ELSE program_start_date
END
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861. 00000 -
>   "literal does not match format string"
>   *Cause: Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace). If the
>   "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
>   with no extra whitespace. 
>   *Action: Correct the format string to match the literal.

I tried inserting `to_date()` in the first two cases, but I'm still getting the same error message. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please share the failing expression with the `to_date` call?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work:                      WHEN floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, to_date(program_start_date))/12) <= 5 THEN '5 years or less'
                     WHEN floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, to_date(program_start_date))/12) > 5 THEN '6+ years'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression implicitly assumes that the database's default `nls_date_format` matches that of the column, which as you saw, simply isn't true - and even if it was, it's a bad practice to make that assumption, as it makes your code as fragile as a butterfly wing.

Instead, you should explicitly state the format, using the [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) function:

```
CASE
   WHEN floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, TO_DATE(program_start_date, 'YYYMM'))/12) <= 5 THEN '5 years or less'
   WHEN floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, TO_DATE(program_start_date, 'YYYMM'))/12) > 5 THEN '6+ years'
   WHEN program_start_date is null THEN 'Blank'
   ELSE program_start_date
END
```